# e.keyCode does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keycode

I would like to ask you about something that does not work for me ? If you could help me please.

Html:

```
<input type='text' class='blabla' onkeyup="function(id, e);">
```

Javascript Code:

```
function(id, e) {
  var comment = $(".blabla").val();`<br />
  // alert(message);  WORK
   alert(e.keyCode) 
 // DOES NOT WORK
}
```

Comment: u declare function as such: 
function foo(evt) { ... }, as for key code: var keycode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;

Comment: Give a name to a function and try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With minimum modifications ,

```
<input type='text' class='blabla' onkeyup="doSomething(e)">

function doSomething(e){
var comment = $(".blabla").val();
var id = this.id;
alert(e.keyCode) // Now it should work
}
```

The first parameter in the doSomething function will be the event object.
The `this` variable will return a reference to the input element.

If you modify your posted js and provide a name to the function as I have done without making changes to the function parameters, you will find that `id` will contain the event object.

Comment: I just messed up everything above, sorry, and thank you

Answer (score 1):

First give function a name .Lets say `function keyfinder` .Then call it on keyup as `onkeyup="function keyfinder(id, event);"`

Then try the following:

```
function keyfinder(id, e){
var eventval = e || window.event;
var comment = $(".blabla").val();
// alert(message); WORK
alert(eventval.keyCode);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `function` as function name in `onkeyup` event.

Answer (score 0):

Function can't be a function name. In your HTML, change `function(id, e)` into, say, `inputKeypress(id, e)`, or any other name you see fit.

In your JavaScript, declare he function like so:

```
function inputKeypress(id, e) {
    do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to give some other name than `function` to a `function`

use `this.id` intead of just `id`

your php file:

```
<input type='text' class='blabla' onkeyup="funkeyup(this.id, e);">
```

Answer (score 0):

You're obviously using jQuery, so you could define the keyup event in your script as well:

HTML/PHP

```
<input type="text" class="blabla" id="mySuperUniqueId" />
```

JavaScript

```
$(".blabla").keyup(function(e) {
  console.log("pressed key with code", e.keyCode, "on id", this.id);
});
```

The anonymous function passed as a handler in `$(...).keyup(handler)` receives the jQuery Event you're looking for. Within that function `this` is set to the DOM Element the event is attached to, in this case the `input` field.
If you intend to work on that field, like using `.val()` you'd have to wrap it in the `$(...)` first:

```
$(".blabla").keyup(function(e) {
  var $input = $(this)
  console.log("current value is", $input.val());
});
```

Just keep in mind, that the value might not have changed, when you're using `keydown` instead of `keyup`.

For more infos on that, take a look at the [jQuery-API](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)